# What is the difference between ftp_fput vs ftp_put?

Tags: php, ftp

In PHP and its manual, i can't clearly find the difference between `ftp_fput` vs `ftp_put`.

- [`ftp_fput`](http://php.net/ftp-fput)
- [`ftp_put`](http://php.net/ftp-put)

Can anyone clarify these two methods please?

Comment: `ftp_fput` seems to accept a file handle, while `ftp_put` accepts a filename.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ftp_fput()` expects an open resource and `ftp_put()` just use a (local) filename

```
ftp_put($foo, $bar, $filename, $baz);
ftp_fput($foo, $bar, fopen($filename, 'r+b'), $baz);
```

Comment: You mean, `ftp_fput` actually reads the file 1 time, before the transfer?

Comment: Nope, I mean `fopen()` use an open stream resource. The both examples above are completely equivalent. Use `ftp_fputs()` if you already have an open resource, or if you want to handle special kinds of resources (like `php://temp`, or a remote resources like `http://google.com` ;)). If you just want to upload a local file, there is no reason to open it yourself first (means: use ´ftp_put()`).

Answer (score 2):

- ftp_fput

  - "Uploads from an open file to the FTP server"
- ftp_put

  - "Uploads a file to the FTP server"

More specifically, `ftp_fput` takes a resource created with `fopen` as the file to upload where as `ftp_put` takes the filename as a string.

Answer (score 1):

`ftp_put` requires a filename, while `ftp_fput` takes a file handle:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, "remote_file_name.txt", "local_file_name.txt", FTP_ASCII);
```

but

```
$file_handle = fopen("local_file_name.txt", "r");
ftp_fput($conn_id, "remote_file_name.txt", $file_handle, FTP_ASCII);
```

Comment: Oh, ok now i see `ftp_fput` needs the file to be opened before. Hmmm.. What is the good point to read the whole file before transfer? :( So i don't think it is a good method to choose.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of my answer: Opening a file doesn't read it (yet). To read a file, use `fread()` ;) And yes: It's not useful to open it yourself, if you don't need it open.

Comment: A `fopen` won't read the whole file, it just opens it. Usually, a `ftp_put` will be the method of choice, but if you validate the file's content beforehand, you can use the `ftp_fput`. You still could use `ftp_put` after validation, but this is less secure when using linux (the file may be re-created while your file is open).

Answer (score 0):

`ftp_fput()` allows starting from a position in the file.